# How to add custom shape in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

There are many shape available but how to add our own custom shape ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create .png format image with square fit image(height and width same).
2. Copy in My Tableau Repository, by default the repository in Document folder.
3. Refresh or restart your Tableau you custom logo will be there.

[image]